# Bind DataTable to WPF DataGrid with Customized Columns

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I want to bind datagrid with datatable, so that it could display and update the data back to the database automatically. But meanwhile i also want to customize the columns of the datagrid, for example for one particular column of datatable, i want to display this column's data in combobox inside the datagrid (the changed data through combobox should be stored back to database as well). How can i do this ? I am new to WPF, so any sample regarding it would be helpful for me.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the DataGrid's AutoGenerateColumns to false, then specify your own column list. Here's a rough example:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Path=MyDateColumn, StringFormat={}{0:MM/dd/yy hh:mmt}}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=NameColumn}" />
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="SomeValue">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource ComboBoxItems}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SomeValueColumn}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: I want to display combobox inside grid at runtime. The scenario is my datagrid is connected to datatable, at runtime this grid will be populated with the data of datatable, so at that point i want to display the value of one column in combobox, that should be displayed inside datagrid. I want to create columns of datagrid at runtime as they could vary depending upon datatable. Any example for doing this...